# spring boot stops immediately, no exception thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app, it is just the basic example project. When I build the app and run the jar, the app stops at startup without actually launching the app. I get some output from the spring code, and I noticed that it is the same as what I see when I build the jar, but tomcat does not start. Does anyone know why the app is doing this?

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Output when running

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.12)

[2023-06-15 18:02:39.813] - 70503 INFO [main] --- com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_352 on machine16 with PID 503 (~/sv/lib/d-test.jar started by user6 in ~/sv)
[2023-06-15 18:02:39.838] - 70503 INFO [main] --- com.example.demo.DemoApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2023-06-15 18:02:40.883] - 70503 INFO [main] --- com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Started DemoApplication in 1.828 seconds (JVM running for 2.387)
```

Output when building jar

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.12)

2023-06-15 18:07:10.050  INFO 123133 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : Starting DemoApplicationTests using Java 1.8.0_352 on machine16 with PID 8372 (started by user6 in ~/sv/demo)
2023-06-15 18:07:10.051  INFO 123133 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-15 18:07:11.185  INFO 123133 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : Started DemoApplicationTests in 1.347 seconds (JVM running for 2.184)
```

Comment: If you want a Web application you should add spring-boot-starter-web dependency.

Comment: Have you added any spring boot starters dependencies?